# Lotus: Need to create a file in remote server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a doubt, as I am new to lotus notes technology. I have to create a file in the remote server. So I have created a java Code and I have added that java file in the Agent and started that agent. But it is not creating the file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Create {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("C:\\aspr.txt");

        try {
            if(f.createNewFile())
            {
                System.out.println("File is Created");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("FILE IS NOT CREATED");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have created one java Agent and added this above code. I always have the message

> FILE IS NOT CREATED

in my log files

My Question is: can you add this code in java agent or we have to do it in some other way as it is not working, or should I add the Credentials to this one as I am using remote server.

Comment: Do you have "Run unrestricted Agents"- right on server and is agent set to run with "Allow Restricted operations"- settings?

Comment: Please answer: What OS and version is your server? And is Domino started as a service, or running as a regular application?  Also, have you tried creating a file 'aspr.txt' without specifying the path? That should probably be created in the Domino Data directory (possibly C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Domino\Data, but your installation may vary).

Comment: Some OS versions make it very difficult to make files in the root even for users logged into the UI.  Try as Richard suggested, try it without the path or create a subdirectory and explicitly use that.

Comment: Windows Server Richard ... Version will let you know and is there ay other way to create a file in server from lotus domino program If you hvae then please let me know about it. I just want to create a log file as lotus domino holds only 7 days logs file. So i need to create a file in E drive and i application need to write a file

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `LotusScript` routine, which you can translate to `Java`:

```
Function getFolderRemote( serverRemote$, folderLocal$) As string
    getFolderRemote$    = |\\| & serverRemote$ & |\| & Left$( folderLocal$, 1 ) & |$| & Mid$( folderLocal$, 3 )
End Function
```

This returns the filepath for the folder on the remote Windows server. Note that it takes out the colon and inserts a $ in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 security features to check. First as Torsten mentioned is the agent security (level and who runs the agent). Additionally as you are using java, you probably have to deal with java security and domino. see [this](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5)
or [this](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-97WPR9) for additional hints